# Makefile .c.o when there is no *.cpp file

Tags: c++, c, templates, makefile

So basically. My makefile has this rule:

> .c.o :
>   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(TESTFUNINCLUDE) -c $< -o $@

which works very nicely until I add some new template functions in a new hpp file... I put everything in my hpp file and my cpp is completely empty.  However if I delete my cpp file, gnu make says.

> make: *** No rule to make target `myfile_template.o', needed by
>   'blahblahblah'

I can solve this problem by just keeping an empty `myfile_template.cpp` file in the folder.  But I feel like this is an ugly solution. Any better ideas?.

Comment: The real question is "why does blahblahblah need myfile_template.o?"

Comment: Your makefile rule is for C files - not .cpp files

Comment: Actually it works with cpp files as well.  No problem there.

Comment: yeah.  Why does blahblahblah need that library...  That makes sense.  I should not have an hpp floating around with no cpp file.  It should just be part of another header.  Thanks.

Comment: The rule in the OP is to compile `.c` files to object files (extension `.o`). You need a rule `.cpp.o`. Makefile has implicit rules

Comment: @WilmerEHenaoH - why not have header files without the corresponding .cpp file. There can be lots of reasons to just have a header file. Templates being one of them.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-versus-Implicit . And there is more, what does `$<` translate too? I am not a make guru, but in the doc it expands to the prequisits which is an empty string if I am not mistaken...   Have you tried patterns like `%.o: %.c`?

Comment: I would also highly advise using [automatic prerequisite generation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Prerequisites) so any future headers you add implicitly trigger recompilation of depending source files automagically (and yes, includes of includes are expanded appropriately).

Comment: If what you really have are C++ files that you are disguising as C files by naming them with extension .c, you just have been (un-)lucky so far. C and C++ are different languages, don't compile C++ programs as C.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be very comfortable writing raw `Makefile`'s, hence I suggest you switch to a more highlevel build tool, such as [CMake](http://www.cmake.org) or [SCons](http://www.scons.org). Other popular candidates are [tup](http://gittup.org/tup), [Waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/), [Gyp](http://code.google.com/p/gyp) or [Premake](http://industriousone.com/premake).